# Golang SQL Scan interface - scan into interface field type?

Tags: go

So I have a struct, something like this:

```
type Torrent struct {
    ID       uint64   `db:"id"`
    Metadata Metadata `db:"metadata"`
    Category uint8    `db:"category"`
    // Many other fields
}
```

`Metadata` is an interface type, in SQL is a LONGTEXT (MariaDB's JSON type). So I have something like this:

```
type Metadata interface {
  // multiple funcs
}

type Category1 struct {} // implementing Metadata interface
type Category2 struct {} // implementing Metadata interface
```

What I would like to do is somehow scan the data from SQL into the exact struct based on the `Category` field. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Since you don't know the Category beforehand you'll have to store the metadata into a temporary value, then after the row scan is finished, inspect the Category and decide how to unmarshal the temporary value into metadata.

Comment: I'm using sqlx and to be fair I was trying to do something like an "after" hook, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do with that. I don't really want to manually do it every time I select this type of data. Is there an example for this somewhere?

Comment: You could do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/0VzgC6MBz7K and to avoid writing it too many times, just abstract the steps into a function.

Comment: ... i don't use sqlx so i'm not at all sure whether it will utilize the scanner interface or not.

Comment: Yeah, sqlx can utilize the scanner interface. Where would I use `TempCategory` though? I feel like it's there but not used.

Comment: The idea is that each time before scanning the struct, you set the Metadata field to an instance of *TempCategory, and because *TempCategory implements not only the Metadata interface but also the sql.Scanner interface sqlx should notice that and call the Scan method, then after the scan is done you pass in the Category value to the TempCategory's unmarshal method, and based on that value you unmarshal the data, passed to Scan during scanning, into the correct Category type and then return it.

Comment: Basically a 3 step process, (1) before scan allocate and set TempCategory, (2) scan, (3) after scan unmarshal data into correct Category type

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Too bad there isn't an "easier" way. :/

Comment: Just a followup question: is that possible that I implement the scanner interface for the base struct (Torrent) and somehow magically just scan (?) every field except the Metadata one, and after that's done I could do whatever based on the Category field?

Comment: I do not think it is, but again, I don't know enough sqlx to be for sure.